# How to sort the list according to the condition?

Tags: reactjs

I have two tables, in the first I store companies, and in the second orders of these companies, but that if you create an order for a specific company and then remove the company from the list of companies, then there will be an error.
How to display only those orders that coincide with existing companies, that is, if there is no company, then there is no order.

Now I’m trying to do something like this, but I can’t understand what’s next ...

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const arr1 = {
    company: [
      {
        id: "random1",
        companyName: "Apple"
      }
    ]
  };

  const arr2 = {
    projects: [
      {
        id: "random1",
        companyName: "Apple",
        descProjects: "Desc1"
      },
      {
        id: "random2",
        companyName: "Samsung",
        descProjects: "Desc2"
      }
    ]
  };

  const blockCreate = () => {
    return arr1.company.map(item => {
      const projects = arr2.projects.filter(i => {
        return i.companyName === item.companyName;
      });

      return (
        <p>
          <span>ID {item.id} - </span>
          <br />
          {item.companyName}
        </p>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{blockCreate()}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to filter your second array before mapping it.

You can try something like this:

```
const companies = arr1.company.map(company => company.companyName); // ["Apple", "Microsoft", ...]
const projects = arr2.projects.filter(project => companies.includes(project.companyName));

projects.map(project => (
   <p>
     <span>ID {project.id} - </span>
     <br />
     {project.companyName}
   </p>
))
```

Comment: For some reason, nothing is displayed, but if displayed in the console, it works ...
https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-bush-zlyi6